# Rounding values in list when using itertools.accumulate function

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers rounded to the tenth:

```
myList =
[2.3,
 14.4,
 21.6,
 6.0,
 2.6,
 4.2,
 7.6,
 46.7,
 8.1,
 1.2,
 7.6,
 6.2,
 8.3,
 17.7,
 27.3,
 5.4,
 18.6,
 6.4,
 6.4,
 40.4,
 28.4,
 36.0,
 21.5,
 4.7,
 19.6,
 22.0,
 18.2,
 19.9,
 12.1,
 20.7,
 1.0,
 11.8,
 1.1,
 3.2,
 8.0,
 6.5,
 4.3,
 6.4,
 4.3,
 16.7,
 17.8,
 2.7,
 7.5,
 1.5,
 2.5,
 7.8,
 4.4,
 10.2,
 14.8,
 25.1]
```

When I feed this list into the `itertools.accumulate` function and generate a new list (i.e. a running total), some of the values have several decimal places due to floating-point arithmetic.

```
from itertools import accumulate

accumulated_list = list(accumulate(myList))
accumulated_list
```

Outputs to:

```
[2.3,
 16.7,
 38.3,
 44.3,
 46.9,
 51.1,
 58.7,
 105.4,
 113.5,
 114.7,
 122.3,
 128.5,
 136.8,
 154.5,
 181.8,
 187.20000000000002,
 205.8,
 212.20000000000002,
 218.60000000000002,
 259.0,
 287.4,
 323.4,
 344.9,
 349.59999999999997,
 369.2,
 391.2,
 409.4,
 429.29999999999995,
 441.4,
 462.09999999999997,
 463.09999999999997,
 474.9,
 476.0,
 479.2,
 487.2,
 493.7,
 498.0,
 504.4,
 508.7,
 525.4,
 543.1999999999999,
 545.9,
 553.4,
 554.9,
 557.4,
 565.1999999999999,
 569.5999999999999,
 579.8,
 594.5999999999999,
 619.6999999999999]
```

I've referenced some mainstay postings and tutorials but can't get a fix to work on my `accumulated_list`:
[Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points/455634#455634)
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

How can the *values* be resolved to a number rounded to the tenth again? (Not formatting the printing, but rounding the value.)

I've tried using
`list(numpy.round(accumulate(myList),1))`
or setting the number to a decimal using the `decimal` module but to no avail.
`list(accumulate(myList.quantize(Decimal('0.1'))))`

Adding more information regarding implementing elements as a decimal. `myList` from above is generated from a function. How can the elements be implemented as a `decimal`?

```
import numpy as np

def simulate(mean, size):
    return list(np.round(np.random.exponential(mean, size), 1))

myList = simulate(15, 50)
```

Comment: Can you make your original `myList` use `decimal.Decimal` for all elements *before* running the `accumulate`? That would solve your issues

Comment: Not in this scenario but I agree controlling the value upstream would be best.

Comment: @jamylak I'm revisiting this. I added the logic to the original post about how `myList` is generated. They are created from a random exponential distribution sample, but I don't see how to implement `decimal` for the elements.

Comment: Ah okay in the original post it didn't mention `numpy`, looks like a `numpy` specific solution would be a better approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `round` them to single decimal place:

```
accumulated_list = list(map(lambda x: round(x, 1), accumulate(myList)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
import numpy as np
accumulated_list = np.around(np.cumsum(myList), decimals=1)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can round the results with the `round` function. Use `map` and a `lambda` function to do this for every item yielded by `accumulate`.

```
accumulated = map(lambda x: round(x, 1), accumulate(myList))
print(list(accumulated))

# outputs the following list
[2.3, 16.7, 38.3, 44.3, 46.9, 51.1, 58.7, 105.4, 113.5, 114.7, 122.3, 128.5, 136.8, 154.5, 181.8, 187.2, 205.8, 212.2, 218.6, 259.0, 287.4, 323.4, 344.9, 349.6, 369.2, 391.2, 409.4, 429.3, 441.4, 462.1, 463.1, 474.9, 476.0, 479.2, 487.2, 493.7, 498.0, 504.4, 508.7, 525.4, 543.2, 545.9, 553.4, 554.9, 557.4, 565.2, 569.6, 579.8, 594.6, 619.7]
```